# Listado noticias AJAX. Enlace a página detalle. Paso de parámetros

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

tengo un listado de noticias dinámicas que obtienen datos JSON de un archivo PHP en servidor.

El listado me aparece correcto, todo funciona. Pero necesito abrir una página detalle de cada noticia en un archivo .html aparte (una app híbrida), este es el código. El PHP no lo pongo , pues supongo que no hará falta (me recoge bien los datos).

No tengo ni idea de cómo pasar el parámetro de la id de la noticia, si vía POST o GET o cómo. Alguna sugerencia?

```
                         <script>
                               var url="recojolosdatoscorrectamente.php";
                                   $("#div_Result2").html("");
                                   $.getJSON(url,function(clientes){
                                   $.each(clientes, function(i,notice){
                                   var newRow =
                             "+notice.titulo+"<a href='detalle.php?identificador="+notice.id+"''>link</a>"                           

                                   $(newRow).appendTo("#div_Result2");
                                   });
                                   });
                                   </script>    

                                   <!--muestro el listado-->
                                   <div id="div_Result2"></div>
```

Se me ha ocurrido pasarlo así, pero obviamente el .html destino no me recoge el valor... Se cómo recoger los parámetros desde PHP (detalle.php) y gestionarlo, pero no se cómo enviarlos vía AJAX y mostrarlo en detalle.html

```
           "+notice.titulo+"<a href='detalle.php?identificador="+notice.id+"''>link</a>"
```

Alguna sugerencia?

NOTA: He pensado antes en mostrar los parametros en línea en cada registro, pero necesito que abra en una página nueva.

Comment: No entiendo por qué quieres cargar un archivo HTML si puedes cargar un archivo PHP con la información de la misma forma que dices: `detalle.php`.

Comment: Porque, como menciono es para una App híbrida. Intel XDK no trabaja con PHP, es decir, sí trabaja pero no se comunica directamente con el servidor, tengo entendido.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo he resuelto de la siguiente manera. Era necesario sacer el **form** del **each**.

```
                               var url="recojolosdatoscorrectamente.php";
                                   $("#div_Result2").html("");
                                   $.getJSON(url,function(clientes){

                                   var contenido = "<form action='detall.html'>";

                                   var newRow = "";

                                   $.each(clientes, function(i,notice){
                                   newRow = newRow + 
               "<button name='detallID' value='"+notice.id+"' type='submit' class='btn btn-info btn-lg'>detall</button>"                           
                                   });
                                   contenido = contenido + newRow + "       </form>";

                                   $(contenido).appendTo("#div_Result2");
                                   });
```

Usando la función

```
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#enlaceajax").click(function(evento){
    evento.preventDefault();
    window.location.href="detall.html";
    });
   })

    </script>
```

Muchas gracias a todos. Saludos